# What is this autocomplete settings/extension used in this video for VS code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, youtube

I was watching this video on Background-Size and I saw that the autocomplete for this man's VS Code is more descriptive than mine. When he types the border property it auto completes with parameters already filled in. However my VS Code for CSS does not do the same. It just autocompletes the property border without the parameters. How do I configure my VS Code to be like the video. [Video with configured VS Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ez7LvkivQoI) Skip to 1:13 to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is using an `Emmet` abbreviation by typing `bd` and then pressing tab, he didn't pick it from the suggestions! So you have that already, no extensions required. Check out the cheat sheet [here](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) and vscode configurations [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet).